# Rails + Sidekiq: Processing uploaded CSV in the background without saving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a rails 3 app that uses sidekiq for background jobs. I'm using Paperclip for file uploads.

My current action in my controller doesn't work:

```
def tax_rates
  if params[:tax_rates]
    TaxRatesWorker.perform_async(params[:tax_rates].tempfile)
    ...
```

I think it's because the tempfile gets deleted when the job goes into the background (It works when I run it without using sidekiq). How would you recommend I handle this? The file is a big CSV file. Should I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in Sidekiqs documentation:

> This means the arguments to your worker must be simple JSON datatypes
>   (numbers, strings, boolean, array, hash). Complex Ruby objects (e.g.
>   Date, Time, ActiveRecord instances) will not serialize properly.

this means you could persist your file and pass the path as string to sidekiq

Comment: The file is big though. Is there another way other than saving the file locally?